# What does 一事 mean in 美国总统特朗普在被问及前顾问班农被捕一事时表示?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand 一事 in the following snippet:

> 《纽约时报》白宫记者Michael D。 Shear 8月20日报道称，美国总统特朗普在被问及前顾问班农被捕**一事**时表示：“我感觉非常糟糕。我已经有很长一段时间没有和他打交道了。我根本没有和他打过交道，对这个项目一无所知。对班农先生来说，这是很悲伤的事情，也很意外。”
> <sub>[特朗普回应班农被捕：我对这个项目一无所知](https://news.sina.com.cn/w/2020-08-20/doc-iivhuipn9787295.shtml)，2020年08月20日</sub>

Breaking apart the relevant part:

> 美国总统特朗普在被问及前顾问班农被捕一事时表示

- 美国总统特朗普 = "US President Trump"
- 在……时 = "when" (short for 在……的时候)
- 被问及 "asked to touch upon"; here I think 及 is short for 涉及 = "to touch upon".
- 前顾问班农被捕 = "former adviser Bannon's arrest"
- 一事 = "a matter" (???)
- 表示 here basically means "said" (but more formal)

**Question**: What does 一事 mean in 美国总统特朗普在被问及前顾问班农被捕一事时表示?

I feel there's something to this, since 一事 is used in other contexts:

> 他设法把话题从他离婚**一事**上引开。 [source: [YouDao](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%B8%80%E4%BA%8B)]
> 他辩称路上人多而把迟到**一事**推脱得一乾二净。 [source: [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%80%E4%BA%8B)]

It reminds me of when we say something like “十”这个字.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

一事 is short for 這一件事 (this thing; this event; this matter)

In your post, '前顾问班农被捕' is the event

"前顾问班农被捕(一事)" = "(the event of) 前顾问班农被捕"

Similarly:

他设法把话题从他离婚一事(這一件事)上引开

他辩称路上人多而把迟到一事(這一件事)推脱得一乾二净

一事 can also be used literally as "one thing" (mostly in classical Chinese)
e.g. 在下有**一事**相求 - There's **one thing** that I wanted your help